# Real Time Clock Calendar Mode & CCS Debugging infomation, MSP430

Tags: msp430

this is my msp430 rtc calendar mode intrrupt test code. it does't work.

I think that I need debugging my program.

```
#include <msp430f5529.h>

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
    //MSP430x5xx and MSP430x6xx Family User's Guide 574 Page
    P1DIR |= BIT0; // P1.0 output
    P1OUT |= BIT0; // P1.0 output HI, LED On
    RTCCTL01 = RTCBCD + RTCMODE + RTCTEVIE;
    RTCCTL01 |= RTCHOLD;
    RTCSEC = 0x00; // Set Seconds
    RTCMIN = 0x00; // Set Minutes
    RTCHOUR = 0x00; // Set Hours
    RTCDOW = 0x00; // Set DOW
    RTCDAY = 0x21; // Set Day
    RTCMON = 0x08; // Set Month
    RTCYEAR = 0x2014; // Set Year
    RTCCTL01 &= ~RTCHOLD; // Enable RTC
    _EINT();
    while(1);
}

#pragma vector=RTC_VECTOR
__interrupt void handle_rtc_interrupt(void)
{
    P1OUT ^= BIT0; // LED flip
}
```

[image]

but there is not RTCNT1~4 register in CCS6 Debugging session.

so my question is 1) which code is wrong in my code? 2) how can I debug my program? debug RTC Timer??

Comment: there are a bunch of examples in CCS, given by engineers in TI. i haven't touched MSP430 for 2 years therefore i cannot give you the answer. but just by reading your code, is that correct you put 0x2014 in the year register instead of 2014?

Comment: I think it's right because i set RTCBCD Flag.